# OpenLayers3 not stopping pending tile requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, gis, openlayers-3

I'm using `OL3` `ol.layer.Tile` with `ol.source.XYZ` to load tiles from a specific tile server.

Panning and zooming the map I noticed that the old pending tile requests (for example, the ones made to load a previous zoom level) are not automatically aborted, they keep going until they get a response. This doesn't happen with Leaflet.

Is it a bug? What should I do in order to get pending tile requests aborted by `OL3`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in an answer too.

In the meantime with just ol3 one solution is to manually handle the tiles through a load function (I like to use promises, but easy to rewrite the below without one), set a timeout, and proceed.  The code below is a bit overdone for just the purpose of a timeout but useful if one wants to manipulate the tiles before presented on the map.

```
tileLoadFunction: offline.get_tile_function(layername),

function get_tile_function(layername) {
return function my_tileLoadFunction(it, s) {
    var ie = new Image();
    var clock;

    var p = new Promise (function (win, fail) {
        ie = it.getImage();

        clock = setTimeout(function() {
            return fail(Error('skipping tile, source for '+layername+' +
            +took too long to provide img data'));
        }, 3000); 

        getRemote();

        //all one has to do is win(s) the source (s)
        //but instead, get the image and do something with it...
        function getRemote() {
            //... like calling a canvas context pixel manipulation subroutine
            pixelManipulate(s).then(function(newpixeldata) {
                return win({image or image data})
            }, function (err) {
                return fail(Error('problem playing w/pixels'))
            })
        }
    })


    p.then(function(data) {
        if (clock) clearTimeout(clock)
        ie.src = data;
        ie = null;
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) console.log(error)
        ie.src = '';
        ie = null;
    });
}
})
```